# SQL query with one blank parameter?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, powerquery

I have written a SQL script to Excel Power Query that fetches values from an Oracle database. My query consists of named excel cells that include date range, "product" and "analysis" and when all these parameters are entered it works perfectly.

There are instances where I would like to return all results from certain date range for a certain "product" if the "analysis" field is left empty. In general terms return all rows of a database entry instead of a specific row if a parameter field is empty.

Due to the nature of the data in the database I had to use Text.From to get the query to recognize search parameters from the named cells. This however generates a problem with the empty cell

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text.

I should probably add that SQL is still quite a new world to me.

Now if I completely remove the parameter (** between these **) from the script, it works as intended. That gave me an idea to use an if-then else statement to make the whole parameter "disappear" if the named cell is empty. However something is wrong with the syntax and it still gives me the "Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text."

Thanks in advance

```
    analysis = Excel.CurrentWorkbook () {[Name="analysis"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    product = Excel.CurrentWorkbook () {[Name="product"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    startdate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook () {[Name="startdate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    enddate = Excel.CurrentWorkbook () {[Name="enddate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    sqlstartdate = Date.From(startdate),
    sqlenddate = Date.From(enddate),    
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=xxdatabase", "SELECT S_SAMPLE.COLLECTIONDT , S_SAMPLE.S_SAMPLEID , S_SAMPLE.PRODUCTID , S_SAMPLE.U_CORNNR , S_SAMPLE.U_REACTORNR , S_SAMPLE.U_ADDITIONALINFO , S_SAMPLE.U_MATERIALNUMBER , SDIDATAITEM.PARAMID , SDIDATAITEM.DISPLAYVALUE , SDIDATAITEM.DISPLAYUNITS#(lf)#(lf)FROM xx.S_SAMPLE#(lf)#(lf)LEFT JOIN xx.SDIDATAITEM ON S_SAMPLE.S_SAMPLEID = SDIDATAITEM.KEYID1#(lf)#(lf)WHERE PRODUCTID='" &Text.From(product)& "' AND **if [analysis] = null then "" else [PARAMID='" &Text.From(analysis)& "']** AND COLLECTIONDT between TO_DATE('" &Text.From(sqlstartdate)& "','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('" &Text.From(sqlenddate)& "','DD.MM.YYYY')#(lf)")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting

"Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text."

Then wrap the expression as

```
 = try Text.From(something) otherwise "something else"
```

but in general I think you are looking for this

```
let x= "WHERE PRODUCTID='" &Text.From(product)& "' AND",
y=if [analysis] =null then "" else "[PARAMID='" &Text.From(analysis)& "']"
combinequery=x&y,
in combinequery
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write queries which will work in Excel so I'm just guessing, but - hopefully - you'll be able to do something with it.

This is your current `where` clause:

```
WHERE PRODUCTID='" &Text.From(product)& "'
  AND COLLECTIONDT between TO_DATE('" &Text.From(sqlstartdate)& "','DD.MM.YYYY') 
                       AND TO_DATE('" &Text.From(sqlenddate)& "','DD.MM.YYYY') 
  AND if   [analysis] = null then "" 
      else [PARAMID='" &Text.From(analysis)& "']
```

If possible, rewrite the last 2 lines to something like this:

```
AND ( [PARAMID='" &Text.From(analysis)& "']  or [analysis] = null)
```

Once again: I'm not familiar with that syntax - square brackets, part enclosed into double quotes and stuff.

By the way, in Oracle *nothing* is equal to null so - I'd actually use `IS NULL`

```
AND ( [PARAMID='" &Text.From(analysis)& "']  or [analysis] IS null)
                                                           --
                                                          this
```

Answer (score 0):

I consulted Bing for a while and we devised the following working solution:

```
paramidFilter = if analysis <> null and Text.Length(Text.From(analysis)) > 0 then " AND PARAMID='" & Text.From(analysis) & "'" else "",
```

Adding the that to the definitions will disregard paramid if analysis is empty.

Thanks to everyone!